# Using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis how do you find references to a classes default instance constructor (section 10.11.4 of the C# 4)

Tags: .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using the following code to retrieve a list of all constructors from an `ISymbol` and I just noticed that classes without an explicit constructor show zero child nodes. My goal is to find all places where a class is instantiated (I am currently using `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols.SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync`).

Is there some way to get a symbol for the auto-implemented constructor? If not is there some other way to find places where these classes are instantiated?

```
var ctors = dependant.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.SelectMany(
    r => r.GetSyntax().ChildNodes().Where(
        n => Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpExtensions.Kind(n) == CSSyntaxKind.ConstructorDeclaration
        || Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicExtensions.Kind(n) == VBSyntaxKind.ConstructorBlock));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this which does exactly what I expected.

[INamedTypeSymbol.InstanceConstructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.inamedtypesymbol.instanceconstructors?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_INamedTypeSymbol_InstanceConstructors)